# spring cloud's health.config.enabled is not responding the same way with spring boot3.xx

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I was using spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE in my application with spring-cloud-starter-config and spring-boot-starter-actuator starters.
when i GET request /actuator/health , my app fetches configuration from config server and the following log shows up

> Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888

after migrating to spring boot 3.0.8, the log does not show up anymore despite what the docs are suggesting https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/4.0.3/reference/html/#_health_indicator_2